# Using Express middleware in Firebase Functions HTTPS requests

Tags: javascript, express, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm having a problem using Express middleware with Firebase Functions. In this [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/authorized-https-endpoint/functions/index.js) a function is hooked to the app() instance like so:

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(`Hello ${req.user.name}`);
});

exports.authorizedHello = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

How do I go about having multiple functions using express middleware?

This is one of the ways I've tried solving it but calling the endpoints returns a 404:

```
app.get('/authorizedHello', (request, response) => {
    response.send(`Hello ${request.user.name}`);
})

app.get('/authorizedBye', (request, response) => {
    response.send(`Bye ${request.user.name}`);
})

exports.authorizedHello = functions.https.onRequest(app);
exports.authorizedBye = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I'm sure I'm just doing it wrong. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider that the base path of the cloud function uses your export name, so in this case your valid URLs will be:

```
https://us-central1-<YOURAPP>.cloudfunctions.net/authorizedHello/authorizedHello
https://us-central1-<YOURAPP>.cloudfunctions.net/authorizedHello/authorizedBye
https://us-central1-<YOURAPP>.cloudfunctions.net/authorizedBye/authorizedHello
https://us-central1-<YOURAPP>.cloudfunctions.net/authorizedBye/authorizedBye
```

That's why the example uses `get('*', ...)`. You should see your URLs displayed after the deploy command executes.

You have four URLs because your exporting the same Express app twice.

Comment: Thank you, pointing to /authorizedHello/authorizedHello worked! A follow up question. Is there a way to avoid having the function name twice in the api call?

Comment: I'd suggest just do something like `exports.api = functions.https.onRequest(app);` once. Or `exports.authorized` then `get('/hello',...)` `get('/bye', ...)`

Comment: Or you could make two different express apps and allow `get('*', ...)`. Also clarified in my answer that you currently have four valid URLs.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for your great question. Your question is give me a clue for using template engine .Maybe i'm out of topic of your question . BUT , i just wanna share if anyone want to use template engine like Pug . Look my sample codes here.

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require("express");
const app = express();




app.set("views",__dirname+"/tmp");
app.set("view engine","pug");
app.engine('pug', require('pug').__express);
app.get("/",p3p(p3p.recommended),function(req,res){
   res.render("index");
});
app.get("/login",p3p(p3p.recommended),function(req,res){
   res.render("login");
});
exports.main = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And then you can access that to link like this . 
https://us-central1-[YOURAPP].cloudfunctions.net/main/
https://us-central1-[YOURAPP].cloudfunctions.net/main/login

Sorry for bothering your question. But i had to find my question on google like using "How to use template engine to google cloud functions" i never got the right answer .

I'm just happy because of your sample codes in your question . That's inpiring me to do some improvements. Thank you .
Sorry for my bad english :)